# how to expand org-mode macros in HTML blocks in export to HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, html

I'd like to use org-mode [macro replacement](http://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-replacement.html) to expand macros inside HTML blocks in org-mode export to HTML.

I'd like this...

```
#+MACRO: event-url bar
#+HTML_HEAD: <meta property="og:url" content="http://foo.com/{{{event-url}}}"/>
```

...to export HTML that looks like this:

```
<HEAD>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://foo.com/bar'/>
</HEAD>
```

Based on [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-03/msg00843.html) I tried this:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent
(add-hook 'org-babel-tangle-body-hook
        (lambda () (org-export-preprocess-apply-macros)))
#+end_src

#+BEGIN_EXPORT html :tangle yes
<HEAD>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://foo.com/{{{event-url}}}"/>
</HEAD>
#+END_EXPORT
```

...but that didn't work either.

How can I expand org-mode macros in HTML blocks in export to HTML?